# What are all the possible places a ReferenceError can be thrown?

Tags: javascript, semantics, referenceerror

Given a global variable `exists` that is defined and a variable `notexists`, what is an exhaustive list of where `ReferenceError`s get thrown and don't get thrown? So far I have yes for:

```
notexists;
notexists++;
```

Also curious about special cases where they aren't thrown, e.g.:

```
var notexists = notexists; //equivalent to: var notexists; notexists = notexists;
typeof notexists; //special case?
```

Did I miss anything else?

Rationale: I'm writing a static analyzer and I have to cover all these cases perfectly.

Comment: Look at how JSHint does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing this answer to make the exhaustive list.

Yes:

```
notexists;
notexists++;
notexists.whatever;
void notexists;
notexists();
```

No:

```
notexists = exists;
var notexists = notexists;
typeof notexists;
delete notexists;
```

Comment: Using the property accessor on undefined will always throw a reference error. That has nothing to do with the operator used. `e.g., delete notexists vs delete notexists.whatever`

Comment: @DanHeberden: actually, `delete notexists` will work fine, but `delete notexists.whatever` will throw a `ReferenceError`

Comment: I don't think the "yes" list will be very useful, and it tends to become very large. The "no" list should basically consist of `typeof notexists` and `delete notexists`. The other cases are different, the first one is due to hoisting, and the last one is property access. Are you parsing the code according to the productions from the spec? If you go through the spec, you'll see there are not many cases where that error is thrown. Also, you'll have to consider the scope chain and hoisting.

Comment: @bfavaretto: i'm using a mozilla-parser-api-style parser. the reason for this question is that I'm writing a code converter so that all unbound variables `foo` refer instead to `$GLOBAL.foo`. I had some gotchas where instead of a `ReferenceError`, I was getting `undefined`. Once I fixed that by turning a `foo` into `$GLOBAL.get_var('foo')`, which threw a `ReferenceError` if `foo` didn't exist, then `typeof notexists` started failing when it shouldn't have. So that's the sort of list I'm looking for..

Comment: @Claudiu that was exactly my point "using the property accessor on undefined will always throw a reference error". `delete notexsists.whatever` is *surprise* using the reference operator.

Comment: @DanHeberden" oh yes, gotcha. I misunderstood your comment.